# Multiple Chapter Styles in same Document

Tags: sectioning

I have a newbie question: I have a two-part document and I would like to use a different Chapter styling for each one; I've looked up in this database and "googled" it, to no avail.
Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Please give us an MWE and tell us what you mean by different chapter styling. Ah, and welcome to our site!

Comment: What do you mean chapter styling? Different fonts? Different styles for section headings?

Comment: If you use titlesec (for example) there is nothing stopping you from redefining the chapter style at any point during your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help you? The particular chapter styles chosen are random and lousy. If you want to change section, subsection, part styles you would likewise redefine them.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%original definition
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\LARGE\thechapter}{1ex}
  {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{2ex}}[\vspace{1ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1ex}
  {\vspace{2ex}}[\vspace{1ex}]
%end of original definition

\begin{document}

\part{A Part}

\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}

%another definition
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\filcenter\underline{\MakeUppercase{{\chaptertitlename}}\ \thechapter}}{20pt}{\Huge}
%end of other definition

\part{A second Part}

\chapter{Three plus Three}
\chapter{Four plus Four}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now that I see your reply, Aubrey, I feel a ... newbie: I apologize for having wasted your time, and I thank you and the guys who promptly replied to my question; I thought that the use of titlesec's commands was limited to the preamble, whereas, as I understand it now, they can be used everywhere inside the document. Thank you again!

Comment: No time wasted. If it helps you might want to mark it as answered.