# Change chapterstyle of bibliography/appendix only

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I am looking for a way to change the chapterstyle for the bibliography and two appendices in a thesis. Ideally, I would like to have other headings for the final chapters, that is different from the main chapters. In the new style, bib/appen would be aligned to the left and further towards the header of the page, wheres the main chapters keep their right alignment and overall more fancy style.

I have already done this kind of change for the frontmatter, just by defining a new \chapterstyle{frontmatter}. The ToC, abstract etc are now set in this style. But it has proved much more difficult for the bibliography and appendices. Now my question is, are there any suggestion as to how I can use a differnet chapterstyle for these final chapters?

It looks like the bibliography and appendix chapters are a part of the mainmatter, as there is no backmatter defined in the template. Should I try to move bib/appendix to the backmatter? How could I make a backmatter and assign chapters to it?

Thanks for any help the folks here can provide on this issue!

Comment: This could be helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299463/multiple-chapter-styles-in-same-document

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To be able to make an informed answer, more information is needed, in particular, what document class you are using.  Also, a more precise description of what you would like these appendix chapters to look like would be very useful.

Comment: @barbara beeton From tagging of the question, I think he may be using the `memoir` class.

Comment: @hesham -- Thanks; I missed that.  But the question you linked in another comment isn't, then, relevant, because `titlesec` isn't recommended for use with `memoir`.

Comment: @hesham Yeah, I'm using the `memoir` class. Sorry that wasn't clear.
What I did for the frontmatter:

`\chapterstyle{frontmatter} 
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\scshape\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\chapterstyle{default}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-20pt}   
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{0.7cm}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\scshape\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\kpfonts\scshape\Large\bfseries\color{darkgray}}`

I'd like the bib and appendix to have the same style. I'm new to this, so the code may be a bit clumsy, but it works in my doc.

Comment: I looked into `titlesec`, but saw that it has compatability issues with `memoir`. Maybe there is a better solution that won't cause problems in the memoir class?

Answer (score 1):

With the `memoir` class define another chapterstyle, say `bibappendix`. The `memoir` class does provide a `backmatter` declaration (I don't know what you mean by your template in your question), read the documentation `texdoc memoir`.

Roughly:

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
% define chapterstyles and other preamble stuff
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapterstyle{frontmatter}
% ToC etc
\mainmatter
% chapters and so on
\chapterstyle{bibappendix}
% appendices
\backmatter
% bibliography etc.
\end{document}
```

BTW `\frontmatter` sets the folios in lowercase roman starting from i, and prohibits chapter etc. numbering although they will be added to the ToC. `\mainmatter` sets the folios in arabic numbering starting from 1 and chapters etc will be numbered. `\backmatter` make no change to page numbering but does stop numbering of sectional divisions.